# How do we feel sensations from a tooth surface that is made up of enamel?

Tags: sensation

If enamel does not have any sensory receptors, how do we feel the tactile sensations when we touch our teeth with an object/finger nail?[image: tooth anatomy]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we feel the tactile sensations when we touch our teeth

The same way you feel tactile sensations when you tap a bicycle helmet on you head: the motion (or vibration) is transferred through the material to your head & the nerve endings in your scalp the same as tapping a tooth sends vibrations to the nerves in & at the base of the tooth.